# Overviews/introductions to Interface Builder for experienced developers?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

Any good resources for learning IB (for iOS) for experienced developers?  I've tried reading through the Apple docs several times now, but all the Apple-specific terminology always turns me off.  The official stuff also insists that IB doesn't produce code and so draws no connections there, which is frustrating.

I've managed to put together a few iOS apps, the last couple of times purely in code, but really need to make my peace with IB now.

I guess what I'm really looking for is a translation from Apple's galapagos language to rest-of-the world terms.  Drawing connections from IB to the UI objects generated at runtime would also be great.

Thanks!

PS - I'm aware that there exist cross-platform and other third-party frameworks for development (I've tried them all) and of the official docs.  IB is the only first-class citizen in Apple-land, and is probably quite good once you're used to it, so that's what I'd like to be using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch Paul Hegarty's lectures on iTunesU. Fall 2011, Stanford Uni iPhone Development. Covers Storyboarding very clearly in an early lecture.

Comment: Great suggestion!  I don't really have time to watch the lectures, but the slides are a fantastic overview for developers who already understand OO and C.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Any decent book will help you understand Interface Builder. What I think, is that you are looking for the perfect book/resource, and that doesn't exist. I really enjoyed [iOS5 Pushing the Limits](http://iosptl.com/) , although I am sure that many others have found other enjoyable books. A quick search on google: "Tutorial iOS Interface Builder" will reveal countless resources that you can use. The most important thing: just dive and have fun while doing it.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation!  According to the description, though, that book seems aimed at novice, self-taught programmers.  In any case a book would be far too long;  I'm looking for a concise overview for experienced developers coming from non-Apple backgrounds.  Which, I think, describes a lot of people currently developing for iOS.

Comment: @TylerDaniel hmmm no... `iOS 5 Programming Pushing the Limits is an advanced guide to iOS programming, perfect for experienced developers ready to move beyond the basics.`

Comment: I can see why you suggest it as an "advanced" text.  The description says that "you’ll learn about as much about design patterns and writing reusable code as about syntax and new frameworks."  That's why it seemed to me to be aimed at less-experienced developers.